# Exit for loop inside using keyword

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, fortify, secure-coding

I am using a tool (Fortify), which is detecting a vulnerability in the following block of code:

```
For Each member As Object In CType(members, IEnumerable)
    Using x As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry(member)
         Dim name As String = x.Name
         If name <> deUser.Name Then
             isGroupMember = False
         Else
             isGroupMember = True
             Exit For
         End If
    End Using
Next member
```

It mentions that fails to release an LDAP resource (var X), due to the "Exit For".

As far as I know, statement  "using" dispose the object although don't execute all the block code.
Is that right?
Or should it be done differently?

I Think is maybe a false-positive issue.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement), *"Sometimes your code requires an unmanaged resource, such as a file handle, a COM wrapper, or a SQL connection. **A Using block guarantees the disposal of one or more such resources** when your code is finished with them."* and *"You do not need a Using block for managed resources. However, you can still use a Using block to force the disposal of a managed resource instead of waiting for the garbage collector."* So I don't think you need to worry about it.

Comment: Are you asking if exiting the `for` loop also exits the `using` block? (it does). The question is a little unclear on that point.

Comment: It looks like a false positive to me. Fortify does that sometimes

Comment: @RufusL the question is since there is not reaching the "End Using", the object X is released?
I think that yes, but the issue mentioned by the tool caused me some noise.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarification. Marking as duplicate...